# Xcode 14 Canvas preview wrong for connected device

Tags: iphone, xcode, preview

I had this error already in Xcode 13 but it still persists
in the current version.
When I connect my iPhone XS to preview my SwiftUI app in the canvas, it shows the iPhone 14 Pro layout. However, when I check on Devices and Simulators, it's correctly recognised as iPhone XS.

So when I design my layout, I always have to switch between the iPhone XS simulator for designing, and my real device for testing.

Does anybody know a way to show the correct device in the canvas?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue and I found out that if you want to see the specific device type to canvas, you have to download the simulator for this device.

From the "Windows" tab, choose "Device and Simulators", and then Simulators. At the bottom left of the window, you can add new simulators.

Then choose your device type and download it.

Once you've added a new simulator, you can use PreviewDevice(rawValue: "Your Device Type").

For example:

I added a new iPhone 12 Simulator and use HomeScreen().previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: "iPhone 12"))

[add simulator window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGmSS.png)

After that, I am able to see my screen as an iPhone 12.

Comment: With the help of the previewDevice, I can use it the way it should be. But I have to add the modifier for every Preview, which is a little annoying. I can live with it, but I wonder if there is a way that my device gets recognised correctly.

Comment: Works well after an Xcode restart